# Utility Maximizing Assignment

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, np

I posted this on computer science section but no one replied :(. Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

There is a grid of size MxN. M~20000 and N~10. So M is very huge. So one way is to look at this is N grid blocks of size M placed side by side. Next assume that there are K number of users who each have a utility matrix of MxN, where each element provides the utility that the user will obtain if that user is assigned that grid element. The allocation needs to be done in a way such for each assigned user total utility must exceed a certain threshold utility U in every grid block. Assume only one user can be assigned one grid element. **What is the maximum number of users that can be assigned?**. (So its okay if some users are not assigned ).

**Level 2:** Now assume for each user at least n out N blocks must exceed utility threshold U. For this problem, whats the maximum number of users that can be assigned.

Of course brute force search is of no use here due to K^(MN) complexity. I am guessing that some kind of dynamic programming approach maybe possible.

Comment: Could you please provide an example for an input and a feasible assignment? From the formulation, it seems that each user utility data is the same size as the taget grid, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, I think I made the problem seem even more complicated. Revised it.

Comment: In simple words, assume there are N rooms with each having M items. There are number of people available who could be given zero or more items from each room and they value these items differently. The objective is that anyone who is given these items, must have at least a valuation of U for items from each room.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the problem can be modelled as a [Maximum Bipartite Matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs) problem, which can be solved efficiently with the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). In the left partition `L`, create `K` nodes, one for each user. In the right partition `R`, create `L*M*N` nodes, one for each cell in the grid. As edges create edges for each `l in L` and `r in R` with cost equal to the cost of the assignment of user `l` to the grid cell `r`.

Comment: I think the Maximum Bipartite Matching problem maximizes the total utility. How do you intend to ensure that all users get at least U each if there is a solution which gives some users less than U and some more than U but gets a very high total. (See also my answer. I think this may be a hard problem, but I will be pleased and impressed if you explain to me why it is not).

Comment: Very good point, perhaps I misread the question. Do you understand U to be a global bound or is it defined individually for each user?

Comment: I understand that each user should be allocated a number of cells, such that the utility for that user for the cells assigned to that user must sum up to more to U. So if there are two users there are two collections of cells, each worth a total over U for the user that owns them. Perhaps Shimano will clarify.

Comment: hi guys, thanks for your comments. I am reading and trying to understand your suggestions. Let me clarify. Any assignment to a user must be in such a way that each user must exceed minimum utility U level in each cell (grid block). Otherwise the assignment is invalid. So if there are two users who are assigned and there are two blocks, then sum utility of user 1 in cell 1 must be more than U as well as in cell 2. Same thing for user 2.

Comment: Did not read all, but Maximum Bipartite Matching do not need Hungarian algorithm which is more complicated and slower. One can simply use Augmenting Path algorithm to find maximum bipartite matching

Answer (score 1):

Using a different interpretation of your question than Codor, I am going to claim that (at least in theory, in the worst case) it is a hard problem.

Suppose that we can solve it in the special case when there is one block which must be shared between two users, who each have the same utility for each cell, and the threshold utility U is (half of the total utility for all the cells in the block), minus one.

This means that in order to solve the problem we must take a list of numbers and divide them up into two sets such that the sum of the numbers in each set is the same, and is exactly half of the total sum of the numbers available.

This is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem, which is NP complete, so if you could solve your problem as I have described it you could solve a problem known to be hard.

(However the Wikipedia entry does say that this is known as "the easiest hard problem" so even if I have described it correctly, there may be solutions that work well in practice).

Comment: This totally makes sense; so the problem is NP-hard as it is a generalization of Partition. It might still be solvable by a pseudopolynomial algorithm.